# Problems retrieving data with prisma in Next.js 13 project

Tags: postgresql, next.js, prisma

Im having alot of issues with my Next.js project. I have a a postgres db I set up and I am using prisma. I created a file that pulls all the data i want from a api and stores it in the db. Im now trying to use that data on my page. I have created a file called  connect-db.ts it is in the pages/api directory. I've also tried moving it to the lib directory. I keep getting this error: `Error: PrismaClient is unable to be run in the browser.`. Im not sure what else Im supposed to do here. I've seen other posts about this issue but most just say you cant run prisma in the browser, I know that Im just having difficulties implementing it.

connect-db.ts:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export async function getAllIssues() {
  const allIssues = await prisma.issue.findMany({    
  });

  return allIssues;
}

export async function getProjects() {
  const projects = await prisma.projects.findMany({   
  });

  return projects;
}

export async function getAllData() {
  const allIssues = await getAllIssues();
  const projects = await getProjects();

  return {
    allIssues,
    projects,
   
  };
}
```

this is the dashboard file that uses this data.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import AccessDenied from "../components/access-denied";
import { getData } from "./api/connect-db";


interface Issue {
  id: string;
  url: string;
  title: string;
  identifier: string;
  createdAt: string;
}

export default function Dashboard() {
  const [myName, setMyName] = useState("");
  const [myIssues, setMyIssues] = useState<Issue[]>([]);
  const [pagination, setPagination] = useState({ first: 20, after: null });
  const accessToken = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TOKEN;
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState<any[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getIssues() {
      try {
        const data = await getData(accessToken); 
        setMyName(data.myName); // Use the myName property from the data object
        setAllIssues(data.allIssues.nodes);
        setProjects(data.projects.nodes);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error retrieving data:", error);
      }
    }

    getIssues();
  }, [accessToken]);

  const { data: session } = useSession();

  if (!session) {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <AccessDenied />
      </Layout>
    );
  }

  const createNewTask = () => {
    window.location.href = "";
  };

  const loadMoreIssues = async () => {
    const lastIssue = allIssues[allIssues.length - 1];
    const after = lastIssue ? lastIssue.id : null;
    setPagination((prevPagination) => ({ ...prevPagination, after }));
  };

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="">
        <h1 className="text-6xl py-5">Hi, {myName}</h1>
        <div className="text-3xl my-5">Welcome to your Dashboard.</div>

        <section className="mt-5">
          <div className="text-2xl">
            <button
              className="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-600 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
              onClick={createNewTask}
            >
              New Task
            </button>
          </div>
          {allIssues.length ? (
            <Cards issues={allIssues} linkable={session.role !== "admin"} />
          ) : (
            <div>No issues found.</div>
          )}
        </section>

        {allIssues.length >= 20 && (
          <section className="mt-5">
            <button
              onClick={loadMoreIssues}
              className="bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-200 text-green-800 rounded-md px-3 py-2 mt-2"
            >
              Load More
            </button>
          </section>
        )}
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Im sure im doing something way wrong, but Im learning next.js as I go and how I thought this was going to work did not at all, so now Im kind of winging it and could use some help.

Comment: Did you had a look at this GitHub issue?
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/6219

There are various suggestions on how you can fix this

Comment: there are, and i mentioned i looked at similar problems posts already, the suggestions mentioned aren't helping

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this line

```js
import { getData } from "./api/connect-db";
```

Here you are importing a function which depends on Prisma to your client(react) dashboard which means that you are basically instantiating Prisma on the client.

If you want the data from your /api in your client you have to fetch it. sth like:

```js
const data = await fetch("/api/connect-db")
```

basically you have to use fetch({...}) instead of getData inside your useEffect

Dont forget that your api/connect-db should have a default export sth like

```js
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const allIssues = await prisma.issue.findMany({});

  return allIssues;
}
```